# ListView is not refreshing

Tags: android, listview

I've got problem with my ListView. I'm creating new object and add it to the database by clicking button in the first fragment. In the second fragment I've got listview with objects from my database. Everything works fine but listView in the second fragment doesn't refresh - I see new objects only after restarting app. All solutions like : notifyDataSetChanged don't work :/

Here's my adapter from first fragment:

```
public class ConcertAdapter extendsRecyclerView.Adapter<ConcertAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "fragmentTag";
private static final String TAG = ConcertAdapter.class.getSimpleName() ;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private List<Concert> concertList = new ArrayList<>();
private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = null;
private int selectedRecordPosition = -1;

private MainActivity mActivity;


public ConcertAdapter(Context context, List<Concert> concerts, MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.concertList = concerts;
    this.context = context;
    this.mActivity = mainActivity;
}

public void setListConcert(ArrayList<Concert> concertList) {
    this.concertList = concertList;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, concertList.size());
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.concert_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final float screenWidthPx = holder.itemView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    Concert current = concertList.get(position);
    Log.d("mLog", current.getUrl());
    holder.mImage.setImageUrl(current.getUrl(), MySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader());
    holder.mImage.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (screenWidthPx * 0.50);
    holder.mFav_btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                final Concert favConcert = new Concert();
                favConcert.setTitle(concertList.get(position).getTitle());
                favConcert.setContent(concertList.get(position).getContent());
                favConcert.setDate(concertList.get(position).getDate());
                favConcert.setUrl(concertList.get(position).getUrl());
                try {
                    final Dao<Concert, Integer> concertDao = getHelper().getConcertDao();
                    concertDao.create(favConcert);

                }catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    });
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date concertDate = new Date();
    try {
        concertDate = format.parse(current.getDate());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    DateTime currentDate = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Warsaw"));
    int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(currentDate), new DateTime(concertDate)).getDays();
    String s = String.valueOf(days);
    holder.mDate_btn.setText(s + " dni");
    if (s.equals("0")) {
        holder.mDate_btn.setText("dziś :)");
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return concertList.size();
}
public void setConcerts(List<Concert> concerts) {
    concertList = new ArrayList<>(concerts);
}

public void showDisplay(int position) {


    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("position", position);
    bundle.putString("content", concertList.get(position).getContent());
    bundle.putString("date", concertList.get(position).getDate());
    bundle.putString("url", concertList.get(position).getUrl());
    bundle.putString("title", concertList.get(position).getTitle());

    Fragment fragment = new DisplayConcertFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    mActivity.replaceFragment(fragment);

}


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public NetworkImageView mImage;
    public Button mDate_btn;
    public TextView mBubble;
    public ToggleButton mFav_btn;
    public ImageView mBubbleImage;
    private ConcertFragment mConcertFragment;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImage = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.concerts_niv);
        mDate_btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_btn);
        mImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        mFav_btn = (ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav_btn);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showDisplay(getAdapterPosition());

        //ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
        Toast.makeText(context, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public Concert removeItem(int position) {
        final Concert concert = concertList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        return concert;
    }


}
private DatabaseHelper getHelper() {
    if (mDatabaseHelper == null) {
        mDatabaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context,DatabaseHelper.class);
    }
    return mDatabaseHelper;
}
```

Here's my second adapter:

```
public class FavAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List mRecords;
    private Dao<Concert, Integer> concertDao;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private NetworkImageView mImage;


    public FavAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects, Dao<Concert, Integer> concertDao) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mRecords = objects;
        this.concertDao = concertDao;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        if(convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.concert_item, parent, false);
        if(mRecords.get(position).getClass().isInstance(new Concert())){
            final Concert concert = (Concert) mRecords.get(position);
            mImage =((NetworkImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.concerts_niv));
            mImage.setImageUrl(concert.getUrl(), MySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader());
            final float screenWidthPx = mImage.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            mImage.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (screenWidthPx * 0.50);
            mDateButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_btn);
            Date concertDate = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            try {
                concertDate = format.parse(concert.getDate());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            DateTime currentDate = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Warsaw"));
            int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(currentDate), new DateTime(concertDate)).getDays();
            String s = String.valueOf(days);
            mDateButton.setText(s + " dni");
            if (s.equals("0")) {
                mDateButton.setText("dziś :)");
            }
           // ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_tv)).setText(studentDetails.teacher.teacherName);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And here's my second fragment with ListView:

```
public class FavFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = FavFragment.class.getSimpleName() ;
    private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = null;
    private ListView mListView;
    private int selectedRecordPosition = -1;
    private Dao<Concert, Integer> concertDao;
    private List<Concert> concertList;
    private MainActivity mActivity;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fav_layout, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.concerts_lv);
        mActivity = (MainActivity) getContext();
        try {
            concertDao =  getHelper().getConcertDao();
            concertList = concertDao.queryForAll();
            FavAdapter adapter = new FavAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.concert_item, concertList, concertDao);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mListView.invalidateViews();
            mListView.refreshDrawableState();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView notify");
        return v;
    }


    private DatabaseHelper getHelper() {
        if (mDatabaseHelper == null) {
            mDatabaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(getContext(), DatabaseHelper.class);
        }
        return mDatabaseHelper;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mDatabaseHelper != null) {
            OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
            mDatabaseHelper = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's my first fragment**

`public class ConcertFragment extends Fragment implements MyBackPressed` {

```
private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "fragmentTag";
private static final String TAG = ConcertFragment.class.getSimpleName() ;
public ProgressBar progress;
private ConcertLoader concertLoader;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Context mContext;
private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private MainActivity mActivity;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    JodaTimeAndroid.init(getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_concert_layout, container, false);
    progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.concerts_rv);
    concertLoader = new ConcertLoader(ConcertFragment.this);
    mActivity = (MainActivity) getContext();
    futureConcerts();

    return v;
}
public void futureConcerts() {
    concertLoader.execute();
    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setClickable(false);
}
public void notifyAboutListCreation(List<Concert> res) {
    ConcertAdapter adapter = new ConcertAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), res, mActivity);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the code for your first fragment.

Comment: But in notifyAboutListCreation from fragment1 method I can see that you only refresh the fragment1 list and not both lists..

Comment: Yes because it's method only for fragment1 list - I use it in asynctask with progress bar

Comment: I think that you should use CursorLoaderManager in second fragment. CursorLoaderManager implements observer on database and will call onLoaderReset when data in database is changed.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems a while ago. Are you triggering any UI updates from non-UI threads? Maybe from within listeners? Try using the following code where the UI updates are triggered.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            ...
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mListView.invalidateViews();
            mListView.refreshDrawableState();
            ...
        }
    });
```

Personally, I now have started to wrap any problematic code blocks in a generic try-catch block that catches Exception and see if there are any exceptions I migh thave overseen (using logcat on terminal with tag filter).

(Cannot comment yet, so answering in this way)

Comment: Thanks :) Could you help me and tell me where I should put this code ? I try to do it in my second fragment, but have errors.

Comment: If you put it in your onCreateView() method, you have to first get the corresponding:  `getActivity().runOnUiThread(...)`